# How to get this mask by using Matlab?

Tags: matlab

I have a mask A, the size of which is 64*64*40 double. The values of voxels in mask A are either 0 or 1. The number of nonzero voxels in A are 43193. There are two arrays, B and C. B represents the location (linear index), the size of which is 500*1 double. C represents the values (score values), the size of which is also 500*1 double. B represents the linear index location of C in A. Now I do something as follows:

```
[coords] = convert_pat_idx_to_mask_coords(A, B);
%%% convert the location array B to the location in mask A.
%%% coords=500*3 double, the first column is location X; the second column
 %%% is location Y; the third column is location Z.
A(sub2ind(size(A), coords(:,1),coords(:,2), coords(:,3)))= C;
```

What I did is to assign the values of array C to the corresponding locations of mask A, and the values of the other (43193-500) voxels in A are still 1.

But I did not realize my purpose. My purpose is to create a new mask D, the size of which is also 64*64*40, the same as A. But only 500 voxels in mask D is 1, all the other (43193 – 500 = 42693) voxels are all 0. Can anyone give me a help?

Answer (score 1):

This will create an array, `D`, which has nonzero values only at the indices listed in `B`. Your question is very confusingly worded, but I believe that's what you want. If not, please clarify your question.
If that's the case:

```
D = zeros(size(A));
D(B) = 1;
```

You should probably consider using sparse arrays depending on what else you're doing with these masks.